# Using static libraries compiled C++ under vs80 (Visual Studio 2005) in a Visual Studio project compiling under c++ vs140 (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2005, static-libraries

Is it possible to use a C++ static library (.lib) compiled using vs80 (Visual Studio 2005) in a Visual Studio 2015 c++ project (vs140)?

In terms of similar questions, I found ['Can I use a Visual Studio 6 compiled C++ static library in Visual Studio 2008?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723416/can-i-use-a-visual-studio-6-compiled-c-static-library-in-visual-studio-2008), and the answer seems to be 'yes with caveats' in this case, but I am inexperienced with static libraries and was wondering if the same held true for c++ static libraries compiled under vs80 to vs140.

EDIT: I want to add that the library I am attempting to port is fairly small and simple, and doesn't access globals or rely on 'extern C' in any way

Comment: I would trust this question more [Runtime issues while mixing libraries from different versions of Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947822/runtime-issues-while-mixing-libraries-from-different-versions-of-visual-studio?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reference Bo Persson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you need to build *all* of your code (including libraries you use) with the *exact* same compiler. There's no guarantee that code generated by different compilers (not even different minor versions) can be linked together and produce usable results - it may *seem* to work sometimes, only to turn into nasty and hard to diagnose problems later at runtime, so just don't do that.

Comment: I will recompile all my static libraries under 2015 in this case.